# jquery appendto function is not working newly opened window from javascript

Tags: jquery, jsp, appendto

I have called a JavaScript function say **fun()** from a from one jsp say **a.jsp**. From this function I am opening a new JSP page say **b.jsp** by using window.open() method. After opening the new JSP, I am using following function 
$('#my-first-template').tmpl().appendTo('div_Tag_id');
to append content to the newly b.jsp page.

I have the my-first-template and div_Tag_id in the b.jsp page.

But it is ended up with the error ().tmpl.appendTo() is not a function.
Please someone help.

I think this is not working because the my-first-template and div_Tag_id is not able to find my from the fun() function.

Regards,
Gobu

Answer (score 0):

.tmpl is not a known jquery function. Sounds like you are trying to reference a library that is not available.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention this before, If I am appending in a.jsp it is working fine. That is from which jsp page I am calling the Javascript function it is appending to same page itself. But If i tried to append in newly opened window it is showing error.

Comment: Its more than likely that in the new window, the library that is needed for this function is not longer accessible.

Comment: I have given placed both the jsp in the same folder and more likely both the files are same i just the copied the content to the second and changed the id for the tag alone.

Comment: Yes all my java script funtion are wrapped inside the document.ready

Comment: Please post entire contents of page.